# Google Store Locator

Tags: 7, google-maps

I have installed [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module on a clean Drupal 7 installation. But I can't activate the Google API. I have added the API key in the GEOCODE field. But I still get the error.

Also I got a blanc screen when I add location via the content type Store Location. Maybe because the API key isn't working?

My API key:
[image]

Got it from Google API:
[image]

After clearing the cache, I still get the error:
[image]

And no Google Maps:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you copied the storelocator library in its desired path? (I mean sites/all/libraries/storelocator)

Comment: Yes I have copied the library.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to different keys one for the browser (client side) and one for the server . You already have configured your server key but you need to get a new key from google developer dashboard for the browser side .
then go to google_store_locator.module line 441 and change it to :

```
'js' => array('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&key=' . variable_get('geocoder_apikey_google_client') => array('type' => 'external')),
```